# I need to get the value after specific word

Tags: text-processing, json

I need to get the value of "name" from this line

```
"snapshots": [{"name":"sLVZt","user":"comment","current":"n","created":"2015-03-11 05:28:02"},{"name":"ubg9x","user":"test2",{"name":"lo3Qp","user":"test3","current":"y","created":"2015-03-11 06:02:46"}]}
```

I expect the output to be like this

```
sLVZt
ubg9x
lo3Qp
```

Comment: Welcome on U&L! You seem to have unbalanced braces/square brackets. Is that a typo?

Comment: Since you seem to be working with JSON data (I took the liberty to add that tag), I would recommend using a dedicated tool such as `jq`.

Comment: I still get the last two values with both solutions. I edit the exact line from the json 

"snapshots": [{"name":"sLVZt","user":"comment","current":"n","created":"2015-03-11 05:28:02"},{"name":"ubg9x","user":"test2",{"name":"lo3Qp","user":"test3","current":"y","created":"2015-03-11 06:02:46"}]}

Comment: Well, that _does_ make quite a difference. It probably can still be done with `awk` or `sed` but will be more complicated.

Comment: What operating system are you using? The tools available depend on that. Is this on Linux? Unix? MacOS? BSD? Something else?

Comment: Please update your question and add valid JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on Linux or otherwise have access to GNU `grep`, you can do:

```
$ grep -oP '"name":"\K[^"]+' file 
sLVZt
ubg9x
lo3Qp
```

Alternatively, in Perl:

```
$ perl -lne 'print join "\n", /"name":"([^"]+)/g' file 
sLVZt
ubg9x
lo3Qp
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your JSON document is valid, such as

```json
{"snapshots":[{"name":"sLVZt","user":"comment","current":"n","created":"2015-03-11 05:28:02"},{"name":"ubg9x","user":"test2"},{"name":"lo3Qp","user":"test3","current":"y","created":"2015-03-11 06:02:46"}]}
```

or (since non-data whitespace is irrelevant for the format),

```json
{
  "snapshots": [
    {
      "name": "sLVZt",
      "user": "comment",
      "current": "n",
      "created": "2015-03-11 05:28:02"
    },
    {
      "name": "ubg9x",
      "user": "test2"
    },
    {
      "name": "lo3Qp",
      "user": "test3",
      "current": "y",
      "created": "2015-03-11 06:02:46"
    }
  ]
}
```

then use `jq` like so:

```
$ jq -r '.snapshots[].name' file.json
sLVZt
ubg9x
lo3Qp
```

This extracts the values of the `name` key in each element of the `snapshots` array.

You may also easily filter the result based on the values of the other keys in various ways:

```
$ jq -r '.snapshots[] | select(.current == "y").name' file.json
lo3Qp
```

```
$ jq -r '.snapshots[] | select(.current != "n").name' file.json
ubg9x
lo3Qp
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 sed 's/,/\n/g' file | awk -F '"' '$2~/name/ {print $(NF-1)}'

sLVZt
ubg9x
lo3Qp
```

Comment: Wow very close I got the last two occurrences but not the first one

ubg9x
lo3Qp

Answer (score 0):

A purely `awk`-based solution could look like this:

```
awk -F':' -v RS=',' '$1 ~ /"name"$/ {print $2}' file
```

This will take the input and split the "records" (what usually would mean a *line*) at the `,`, and then all record into fields at the `:`, leaving two fields per record. If the first field *ends* in `"name"` (this accounts for leading square/curly braces), print the second field, which is the value behind the `:`.

If you want to get rid of the bracing double quotes, you can use

```
awk -F':' -v RS=',' '$1 ~ /"name"$/ {gsub("\"","",$2); print $2}' file
```

**Update**

Since your amended sample input contains a leading `"snapshots":`, which also includes the `:` but in an "unbalanced" way, this will not work anymore. Since my answer stated "purely `awk`-based", the only possible adaptation will be much more involved and would look something like:

```
awk '{n=patsplit($0,field,"\"[^\"]*\":\"[^\"]*\""); for (i=1;i<=n;i++) {split(field[i],elem,":"); if (elem[1]=="\"name\"") print elem[2];};}' file
```

Clearly, this is far less elegant than the `grep`-based approaches, and also less portable (will not work on `mawk`,e.g.).

Answer (score 0):

Try also

```
grep -oE ".name.:[^,]*" file | awk -F\" '{print $(NF-1)}'
sLVZt
ubg9x
lo3Qp
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried with Below command, Worked fine

```
perl -pne "s/[ ,]/\n/g" filename| awk -F ":" '/name/{gsub(/\"/,"",$NF);print $NF}'
```

output

```
sLVZt
ubg9x
lo3Qp
```